# PHP/SQL Issue when checking table information if exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

One of my pages will display information from the table if the information exists, however it's outputting an error stating it does not exist.

```
$get_provider = str_clean($_GET['provider']);

$provider_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `payment_providers` WHERE `provider_seo_name`='".$get_provider."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($provider_sql);

$check_provider = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `payment_providers` WHERE `provider_seo_name`='".$get_provider."'");
$provider_exists = mysql_num_rows($check_provider);
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
<?php if($provider_exists == 0) { ?>
<h2 class="page-header">Error!</h2>
<div class="alert alert-danger">You never specified a payment provider to redeem with.</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<h2 class="page-header"><?php echo $row['provider_name']; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $row['provider_description']; ?></p>
```

Information exists in this table and for the specific provider_seo_name but for some reason it won't allow it to display or thinks it doesn't exist. I was having issues with the extensions of the page before and the edit I made was adding .php to locations

I've googled possible causes but I can't figure it out. If you need more information I'll be happy to provide it

Comment: First, you don't need to do the query twice, just do mysql_num_rows() on the first query.  Second, you need to debug your query - echo() the sql and run it in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: get a new book or read a different tutorial. you are learning deprecated and potentially harmful methods. google sql injection and prepared statements.

Comment: No need to use the query twice. `<?php if(!empty($provider_exists)) { ?>`. Also echo the query in browser & run it in mysql CMD or phpmyadmin or workbench.

Comment: I'm very new so I'm working off existing scripts to create my desired project outcome. I will attempt that now and I am learning elements individually and trying to apply them, I'll google that now

Comment: @Pamblam - private void executePrepStat - It's telling me to have a prepared statement to apply to all req to avoid SQL injections?

Comment: Google PDO or MySQLi, these are the APIs that have replaced the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu - <?php if(!empty($provider_exists)) { ?>

I replaced this <?php if($provider_exists == 0) { ?>

Can you give me a very simple explanation on the difference of using those two? As this fixed my issue of displaying the required form but not allowing requests

Comment: Pamblam so I'm using outdated functions eg  mysql_ rather than MySQLI ?

Comment: correct. i've posted an example for you.

Comment: No, I suggested you to remove 2nd query which is not required & will slow your process.To find the issue, you need to echo the sql query.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu - the query itself is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Database info
$host = "localhost";
$database = "crm";
$user = "root";
$password = "bijoux22";

// Create a database connection w/ PDO
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database.';charset=utf8', $user, $password);

// Make a prepared statemnt
$q = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `payment_providers` WHERE `provider_seo_name`= :provider");

// Execute it with your variables
$q->execute(array(":provider"=>$_GET['provider']));

// Get the results
$row = $q->fetch();

// check if there were matches
if(count($row)) // provider exists
else // provider doesn't exist
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you Pamblam you are lots of help!

Answer (score 0):

I can see both have has provided the correct reason as to why it was not functioning

http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

I was using the wrong type when checking the provier_exists !empty works and == 0 doesn't due to it checking the cell value incorrectly

I will also look into MYSQLi rather than the mysql_ functions to avoid this from happening again. Thanks guys